# Add Class to Action Buttons

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm looking for a way to override the cancel and update buttons on a resource. I'm new'ish to Nova.

I would like to add a class to the container for the cancel and update actions (see image). So far I can't figure out how to do that. There doesn't seem to be any unique class names or data attributes that allow me to target this section.

Is there a way to accomplish this?
Are there any concerns I should have if I do?

[image: Adding a Class]

Comment: Micro-customization is the painful part in frameworks like nova. The advantages of the framework come with a price of accepting the existing styles. You can do a lot of productive stuff or you can change a bit of styling(

Comment: Valid point I suppose. I'm coming from the Drupal world and this is my first Nova experience.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, there is no way to add class to these buttons, without modify nova's core. But you can edit styles of existing elements. Check nova's [docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/themes.html) about it.